# Is PHPmyadmin "SAAS"?

Tags: database, definition

AFAIU a SAAS software is any software which is runs on a browser and performs a certain service, (aside of giving a way to contact the owner of that software) and is also aimed for reuse, whether if it's gratis or not.

Is PHPmyadmin, the Database Management Tool (DMA) SAAS actually?

Comment: Do you mean *SaaS*, "software as a service"?

Comment: What is "SASS"? What does this have to do with [a stylesheet language](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: I meant to the former, fixed.

Comment: SaaS is all about the service provider operating the software, easing your maintenance burden. You install PMA on your own server. You have to maintain and update it yourself. So it is not SaaS.

Comment: Gmail is SaaS. Installing a webmailer on your own server is not. Github is SaaS, your own git server is not. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**phpMyAdminitself is *not* "Software as a service". It *could* be part of such a service, but this would be an unusual case.**

"Software as a service" means a customer pays a service provider for the *use* of a software package, with the provider being fully responsible for maintaining, administrating, and hosting the software.

phpMyAdmin itself is open source and hosting it as well as the underlying database, ist completely up to the users.

Even a case where a company hosts a database and allows customers to access this DB via phpMyAdmin would not typically be called "Software as a service", because SQL databases are nowadays seen as infrastructure rather than software that is directly used, and administrating a database (which is what phpMyAdmin  is for) is exactly the kind of thing that the customer isn't supposed to be bothered with in a SaaS model.

Comment: I think that the better question would be what is the software marketing model(?) of PHPmyadmin?

Comment: @user9303970: It doesn't have one. It is free and open source, developed by people who want such a software and are willing to let everyone benefit from their work. That is the original concept of "free software", which is quite opposed to the very concept of marketing and making profit.

Comment: I know what's free software in the sense of allowing usage for any non-immoral (what's moral is another debate) purpose, exposing the source code, allow people to distribute copies (also modified ones) and obligate them to keep their copies free. Yet, you can still have a "marketing model" even for free software which is also gratis; If you think the program is good and you think how to spread it more and maybe also categorize it for that purpose, one can say you have such a model. Maybe the term "distribution model" is better since "marketing" is usually associated with money and profit.